# what are commands for tc shaping,queueing and scheduling?

Tags: linux, shell

I have 3 virtual machines and i fixed them as a team and in 1 local host now they can ping each other and see each other now how can I write a command to see shaping using traffic controller (tc)?
is there any suggestion?