# what is the command for sending files via shell in UNIX

Tags: linux, shell

I have 3 virtual machines and i fixed them as a team and in 1 local host now they can ping each other and see each other now how can I write a command to send 1 file from a virtual machine to another?

How to do this kind of file transfer? Is there any utility for this?

<strike>I have 2 opensuse gnome os and 1 opensuse kde</strike>

I have OpenSUSE running on all the three machines.

Comment: What does `tc` means in the title? Is it a typo for `the` ?

Comment: No tc is a command in linux which you can make scripts tc is abbreviation of traffic controller

Comment: when sharing a file from os1 to os3 the os2 which is in the middle and has 2 network cards(net adapters) should output the traffic but I really don't know what should i do?

Comment: @nikparsa - Your last comment is significantly different than your original question, in which you stated that you had IP connectivity between the machines ("can ping each other").  If you now have another setup, and if os1 to os3 no longer have standard IP connectivity with each other, please open a new question detailing the new configuration.

Comment: (Actually, he already did:  http://superuser.com/questions/376070/what-are-commands-for-tc-shaping-queueing-and-scheduling)

Comment: @ziesemer :) yeah,she

Answer (score 7):

It sounds like you have standard IP connectivity, which makes the fact that you're using VMs pretty much irrelevant.  I'd just use [`scp`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_copy).

just type `man scp` to get more info in this command.

Comment: scp [[user@]host1:]file1 ... [[user@]host2:]file2 does the trick

Answer (score 0):

The most basic file transfer can be handle with `netcat` [`nc`].
In the following example, we transfert `filename` from a virtual machine (`IP=a.b.c.d`) to another one (VM2)  using the port `8000`:

- on VM2 run: `nc -l      8000 > filename`
- on VM1 run: `nc a.b.c.d 8000 < filename`

(if the port `8000` is blocked you can use another one)

OK, this is the most basic solution to use when `NFS`/`rcp`/`scp`/`ftp` are not available.

Note that, `rsync` may be the best file transfer tool when **updating** files (e.g. appending new data always at the end).